# Non Button Login

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angular, html

Suppose I have a Login Page, and the page has the two input fields Email, Password, and a button:

```
 <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
 <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
 <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
 <button type="button">
```

When I click on submit button, it sends the request to the next page, validates the user, and displays the content. But I want the user authorized automatically, and sent to the next page without clicking the button. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the user to type in the username and password and whenever they match successfully you log him in without having him click a button ?

Comment: this is not a right way to do authentication.

Comment: @dhilt yes I want user to match successfully without having to login in the button but I am looking for some more better response...

Comment: If you can edit this question so it is clearer what you are asking, then we'll be happy to consider re-opening it. What would being authorised automatically entail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what response you're looking for. If you need a tutorial, a quick google search can get you [something like this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/23/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial).

But an answer to your question. Yes, you can login and redirect to a home page.

### Edit

If you want to constantly check if the user is able to sign in, which I do not recommend in the slightest for both security and user experience reasons, then bind to the `input` event.

```
<input type="password" (input)="willItSubimt()" />

willItSubmit() {
  if (this.form.valid) {
    this.authService.authenticate(username, password).subscribe(isAuthenticated => this.router.navigate(["/"]))
  }
}
```

If you do this, you will want to debounce the api call.

**I do not recommend this, because it is less secure.**

Comment: Why you do not recommend this can you Explain. @christo8989

Comment: It's less secure. It might also be slower than just having them submit.